# Which model should I use? xtlogit or xtprobit

Tags: panel, stata

I have the following panel data set with very large N (500,000) and small T (15 years). My dependent variable is Project1 or project 2. I want to estimate the likelihood of Project dependent on treated with year and village fixed effects. For the continuous dependent variable, I was using reghdfe.

The dependent variable is simply that when a village gets the project the dummy is equal to 1 and remains 1 for the subsequent years.

I am aware that I cannot use "probit" command in STATA as I have a panel. Can you suggest which model should I use?

```
| village | population | year | project_1 | project_2 |  treated  | 
|---------|------------|------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| A       | 100        | 2001 | 0         | 0         | 0         |
| A       | 100        | 2002 | 1         | 0         | 0         |
| A       | 100        | 2003 | 1         | 0         | 1         |
| A       | 100        | 2004 | 1         | 0         | 1         |
| A       | 100        | 2005 | 1         | 0         | 1         |
| B       | 200        | 2001 | 0         | 0         | 0         |
| B       | 200        | 2002 | 0         | 0         | 1         |
| B       | 200        | 2003 | 0         | 1         | 1         |
| B       | 200        | 2004 | 0         | 1         | 1         |
| B       | 200        | 2005 | 0         | 1         | 1         |
| C       | 150        | 2001 | 0         | 0         | 0         |
| C       | 150        | 2002 | 0         | 0         | 0         |
| C       | 150        | 2003 | 0         | 0         | 0         |
| C       | 150        | 2004 | 1         | 0         | 0         |
| C       | 150        | 2005 | 1         | 0         | 1         |
| D       | 175        | 2001 | 0         | 0         | 0         |
| D       | 175        | 2002 | 0         | 0         | 0         |
| D       | 175        | 2003 | 0         | 0         | 0         |
| D       | 175        | 2004 | 0         | 0         | 1         |
| D       | 175        | 2005 | 0         | 0         | 1         |
```

Comment: Questions about which statistical method or model to use are off-topic on Stack Overflow. This would go better on Cross Validated or Statalist.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has two parts. Which model of Logit and Probit is more appropriate for you, and how to implement the appropriate model in Stata. As @NickCox mentioned, the former is most appropriate for Cross Validated, and has received robust discussion there: [Difference between logit and probit models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20523/difference-between-logit-and-probit-models)
.